# Firewalld with variable source

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl, firewalld

I'm writing a script and I'm stuck.

I have a url (https://file.test.com/tips) that contains a file with the list of network subnets.

File content:

```
{192.168.1.0/24,10.0.0.0/24,2001:aaaa:bbbb:cccc::/64}
```

When I try to run

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-source="$(curl https://file.test.com/tips)"
```

I get

```
Error: INVALID_ADDR: Zone 'trusted': invalid source '{192.168.1.0/24,10.0.0.0/24,2001:aaaa:bbbb:cccc::/64}'
```

It works just fine when I run

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-source={192.168.1.0/24,10.0.0.0/24,2001:aaaa:bbbb:cccc::/64}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I placed a comment earlier but this is more of a bash expansion issue. So the proper way would be to use a loop and split subnets by `,`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read_file=$(curl -s https://file.test.com/tips | sed 's/[{}]//g')

saveIFS=$IFS

IFS=',' read -ra subnets <<< "$read_file"

for subnet in "${subnets[@]}"
  do
    firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-source="$subnet" --permanent
  done 

firewall-cmd --reload

IFS=$saveIFS
```

Or the other alternative is using `eval` or even `printf '%q' "${subnet}"`

Using `eval` which isn't recommended but is fairly secure for what you want.

```
eval firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-source="$(curl -s https://file.test.com/tips)" && firewall-cmd --reload
```